# Azure Web App written in Node.JS with AD security, who is the user accessing this page?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Azure Web App written in Node.JS with AD security, is there a environment variable that can tell me who is accessing this page?

Created Azure Web App.  This works well.  Enabled Azure AD security.  When I access this page it takes me to the Azure sign-in page and then goes to my page.  Is there a environment variable that can tell me who is accessing this page -- i.e., person who just signed in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will find who is logged in in the request header "x-ms-client-principal-name"

Here is how to find the user that is accessing the page (after signing on to Azure Active Directory)

```
const express = require('express');
var assert = require('assert');
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
   var docs = {"Version:": 1.1};
   docs["ALL_ENV_VARS"] = process.env;
   docs["Request Headers"] = req.headers;
   res.status(200).send((JSON.stringify(docs, undefined, 2)));
});
```

You will find who is logged in in the request header "x-ms-client-principal-name"

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve them by using the `context.user.getIdentity()` method. The `getIdentity()` method returns a promise that resolves to an object. You can refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-node-backend-how-to-use-server-sdk#howto-tables-getidentity) for more details.

**Reference:**

[Access user claims](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-authentication-how-to#access-user-claims)